# I want to use Elasticserach and kibana alerts to detect line passing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

We would like to implement a system that draws a line on a map displayed by kibana in advance and　detects when a moving object (such as a boat) passes through the line.
I believe a possible way to do this is to set up rules using Elasticsearch query from kibana's rule creation.
But I don't know how to realize it.

I drew a line by selecting create index in add layer from maps in kibana.
A json file containing location, speed, and time information was imported into elasticserch and displayed on a map.

Comment: You're probably looking for geo-alerting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/geo-alerting.html

Comment: I have already tried, but line passage detection was not possible by the method described here.

Comment: Why not, what was the issue?

Comment: The method described here supports alerts for the type of circle, square and polygon.

Comment: Zoom out a little bit, a boat is on a sea, your "line" can be a "sufficiently big" polygon around the boat